# How to use app only for part of users (30%)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have few questions about my app.

1. How to integrate app on React app?
2. Is it possible and how to use app only for part of users (30%)?
3. How app affects on page speed?

Comment: What do you mean with `how to use appcues only for part of users (30%)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a guide to how to integrate Appcues into react available here https://docs.appcues.com/article/389-single-page-applications-spas . The main part that trips people up is they forget or don't properly integrate the Appcues page call into their router.

   < Router onUpdate={ () => window.Appcues.page() } >
2. There are a few ways you can do this. You can configure appcues to only target 30% of your users and thus only show content to that select percentage, the other way would be to only make the Appcues.identify() call on 30% of your users.
3. You can set the Appcues code to load whenever you choose, this allows you to minimize any impact it might have on your page loading. This doc provides a way to load it asynchronously https://docs.appcues.com/article/32-installing-appcues-asynchronously but typically setting it to load last is more than enough to resolve any page loading concerns.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Router onUpdate has removed in v4